# Generic issue - inferred type does not conform to declared bound

Tags: java, generics, types, type-parameter

We got the following class signatures:

car:

```
public class car<E extends Parts> [...]
```

parts:

```
public abstract class parts<E extends Stuff> [...]

public class Tire<T extends StoneTire> extends parts<T>[...]
```

stuff:

```
public abstract class Stuff [...]

public class Painting extends Parts [...]

[...]
```

We want to save the car in a Treeset < Parts< E>> (in the "Car"-class), but the compiler says nope :[ Because if we try to save a Tire in a City of Tools he cant find the StoneTire type in the bounds of Tool.

Comment: Where is the `M` used in your method declared?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in the method: public final <M extends Museum<E>> void addMuseum(final M museum)

Comment: Please show us what `toolCity` is.

Answer (score 2):

Your method

```
public final <M extends Museum<E>> void addMuseum(final M museum)
```

has its own type parameter `M`, but it also depends on the class type parameter `E`. `M` is bound at the method invocation, but `E` is bound at the declaration of the instance (or of the expression).

You've got

```
toolCity.addMuseum(m1);
```

where `toolCity` seems to be an instance of

```
public class ToolCity extends City<Tool>
                                 // E
```

SO the method being invoked, fully bound, is

```
public final void addMuseum(final Museum<Tool> museum) ...
```

But your `m1`, from the exception message, seems to be a

```
Museum<StoneTool> m1 = ...
```

A `Museum<StoneTool>` is not a subtype of `Museum<Tool>` and can therefore not be used as an argument to something that expects the latter.

Comment: toolCity is a new "City<Tool>" instance! "Tool" is an abstract class and "StoneTool" extends "Tool" so its an subtype?!? The method should accept "Museum" and any subtypes of it and any subtype from "Tool"?

Comment: @horrorhorst No, for a `City<Tool>` the method accepts a subtype of `Museum<Tool>`. `Museum<StoneTool>` is **not** a subtype of `Museum<Tool>`.